# how to display values in a column based on a condition using awk or grep?

Tags: awk, grep, ps

I need to get the list of processes with their process id, cpu%, memory %  having cpu% >0

I am able to get an output using

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu|awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$11}'
```

in the below format

```
PID %CPU %MEM COMMAND.
```

The output gives you a sorted output based on cpu%.

I need to get only the rows which have cpu%>0

I am a newbie to using aux, grep but I guess what I aksed can be done using these tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` does indeed do what you wish:

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu|awk '{if ($3>0) print $2,$3,$4,$11}'
```

Addendum: if you'd like the header as well:

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu|awk '{if (NR==1 || $3>0) print $2,$3,$4,$11}'
```

`NR` is the built-in variable that contains the current line number (strictly speaking, record number.)

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu |awk '$3>0{print $2,$3,$4,$11}'
```

Or just:

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu |awk '$3{print $2,$3,$4,$11}'
```

Since then `$3` needs to be something else than `0`